# Print script output to webpage using Flask

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, flask, wmi

Why is this script not printing the output to a webpage?
It gives me the:

> * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

message but nothing prints to the webpage.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import wmi
ip=['server1','server2','server3','server4','server5']
user="username"
password="password"
append_services=[]

words = 'win32'   


@app.route("/")

def service_status():

    for a in ip:
        global append_services
        print ('\n'+a+'\n')
        c = wmi.WMI (a,user=user,password=password)
        get_names= c.Win32_Service() 



        for y in get_names:
            convert = str(y.Name)
            append_services.append(convert)        
            append_services=[w for w in append_services if w.startswith(words)] 


        for l in append_services:
            state_of_services = c.Win32_Service(Name=l)
            if state_of_services:
                for x in state_of_services:
                    convert1 = str(x.State)
                    convert2 = str(x.Caption)
                    print convert1,"        ",convert2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: If you use `print` it will print on console. If you want to print it on html for user to see, could you try return it (instead of print, i never use this set up) or pass it to your render template then put it into html.

Comment: The return works on the ('\n'+a+'\n') which prints the server name but the return does not work on the 'convert1,"    ",covert2'

Comment: Because when you return, the function stopped already I think. you need to keep them all in a variable, and when you exit the loop, return them.

Comment: Try if you can, or I will try to get a sample code for you in this case, I'm not familiar to Flask so dont expect to much xD

Comment: Thanks !

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
  content = """
     teste
   """
  user = "Hero"
  return render_template('index.html', **locals())

Comment: So you did it? happy

Comment: nope - that was some example code i found - no luck

Comment: Ok I will try to craft a sample

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all the results in a variable, generate your html then return so user can see it. let's try:

```
from flask import Flask
import wmi

app = Flask(__name__)

ip = ['server1', 'server2', 'server3', 'server4', 'server5']
user = "username"
password = "password"
append_services = []

words = 'win32'


@app.route("/")
def service_status():
    results = []  # Temp for result to return to html
    for a in ip:
        global append_services
        print('\n'+a+'\n')
        c = wmi.WMI(a, user=user, password=password)
        get_names = c.Win32_Service()

        for y in get_names:
            convert = str(y.Name)
            append_services.append(convert)
            append_services = \
                [w for w in append_services if w.startswith(words)]

        for l in append_services:
            state_of_services = c.Win32_Service(Name=l)
            if state_of_services:
                for x in state_of_services:
                    convert1 = str(x.State)
                    convert2 = str(x.Caption)
                    results.append([a, [convert1, convert2]])  # Append results
                    print(convert1 + "        " + convert2)

    # This part for generate HTML for return
    html = ''
    for i in results:
        html += '<h2>Ip: ' + i[0] + '</br>'
        html += '<h3>From ' + i[1][0] + ' to ' + i[1][1]

    return html

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: i get a IP but when i go to the url i get a internal server error. Is this working for you ?

Comment: Which url anyway, I did not try it, I just assume your code is working and change the way it export result

Comment: I will test and fix the code in next 24 hours, hope you well

Comment: Update: I ran the script you suggested. It kind of works, but the output to web is meaningless 'IP:....'
From N to O

Comment: I could not understand your comment @@

Comment: The above code outputs the correct data in the terminal but the output in the web browser is different. It says i want it to show the name of the service and then the status.@@

Comment: yes - and i want it to print <server ip>
                                         <Service status>
                                         <Service status>                                         
                                         <Service status>

                                          <server ip>
                                         <Service status>
                                         <Service status>                                         
                                         <Service status>